# Is there a way to profile not only how often a call is made, but also how it was triggered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, profiling, firebug

When profiling my JavaScript with FireBug, functions like `jQuery.clone()` stands for almost 50% of the consumed time:

```
Function  | call|  %  |  own  |  time  |  avg |  min  |  max  |     file 
_____________________________________________________________________________
clone     | 400 | 42% | 840ms | 1332ms | 3s   | 0.1ms | 13.ms | jquery.min.js 
clone     | 138 | 13% | 267ms | 1038ms | 7ms  | 5ms   | 16.ms | jquery.min.js 
template  | 338 | 6%  | 125ms | 185ms  | 0.5ms| 0.2ms | 1.6ms | underscore.js 
fadeImage | 398 | 3%  | 79ms  | 146ms  | 0.8ms| 0.1ms | 2.7ms | ondemand.js
```

I am not calling `clone()` my self, and I have problems understanding why it is called that often. I have a backbone.js app with a lot of subviews - that could be a reason - but thats just guessing.

**Is there a way to profile not only how often a call is made, but also how it was triggered?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use firebug for debugging its possible to use console.trace() which outputs the stacktrace. So you can see which function has called this function.

Comment: so where to I put trace() for clone()? in the jQuery code itself?